# how does computer calculate the float 0.1?

Tags: c++, c, computer-science

i have some interesting curiosity how does computer calculate the float 0.1?
In the wolfram alpha, the query "0.1 to binary" gets binary float infinitely.
But c++ compiler (xcode) calculates 0.1 exactly.
How is it possible?

Comment: Read about the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard. You might also want to read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: C++ compiler doesn't generate 0.1 exactly; it truncates the infinite representation at a finite number of bits.  If you poke really hard, you will be able to spot the difference — but it takes some skill to do the spotting (or abuse of `printf("%.25f\n", 0.1);`).

Answer (score 3):

Because of rounding you can get from the finite binary representation to the original decimal. If you try to print the number with higher precision it will not be exactly 0.1. [Working example](http://ideone.com/pryYwg):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std; 

int main() {
    float f = 0.1f;
    cout << f << endl;
    cout << setprecision(10) << f << endl;
}
```